# Semantic-UI Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

Got a problem with semantic-ui dropdown.

I've been using Semantic-Ui, and wanted to change the dropdown item dynamically.
That is, when i choose the value from the first dropdown, the second dropdown's item will change.
But the thing is, when the items are changed, the second dropdown cannot be chose,
the value won't change. The dropdown won't collapse back.

The HTML

The First Dropdown

```
<div id="programmetype" class="ui fluid selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="programmetype">
    <div class="text">Choose..</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
       <div class="item" data-value="val1">Car</div>
       <div class="item" data-value="val2">Tank</div>
       <div class="item" data-value="val3">Plane</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second Dropdown

```
<div id="servicetype" class="ui fluid selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="servicetype">
    <div class="text">Choose..</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="select">Choose..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

..........................

The jQuery

```
$("#programmetype").dropdown({
            onChange: function (val) {
                if (val == "val1")
                {
                    $('#servicetype .menu').html(
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val1">Saloon</div>' +
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val2">Truck</div>'
                        );
                };

                if (val == "val2")
                {
                    $('#servicetype .menu').html(
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val1">Abraham</div>' +
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val2">Leopard</div>' +
                        );
                };

                if (val == "val3")
                {
                    $('#servicetype .menu').html(
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val1">Jet</div>' +
                        '<div class="item" data-value="val2">Bomber</div>' +
                        );
                };
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it,

I put `$('#servicetype').dropdown();`
after assigning the values:

```
$("#programmetype").dropdown({
                onChange: function (val) {
                    if (val == "fertility")
                    {
                        $('#servicetype').dropdown({'set value':'something'});
                        $('#servicetype .menu').html(
                            '<div class="item" data-value="acp">ACP</div>' +
                            '<div class="item" data-value="art">ART</div>'
                            );
                        $('#servicetype').dropdown();
                    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this overwrites the previous component state, which means you lose any stored "defaults". I filed a bug report: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/953

Comment: Also note that this causes all internal event handlers to be added again - so a 'change' event will be triggered twice. For me, this was undesirable.

Comment: Note: as mentioned in the above issue, as of v.1.0 the correct approach is `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh');`

Answer (score 3):

A workaround approach:

```
function setDinamicOptions(selector, options) {
    var att = "data-dinamic-opt";
    $(selector).find('[' + att + ']').remove();
    var html = $(selector + ' .menu').html();
    for(key in options) {
        html += '<div class="item" data-value="' + options[key] + '" ' + att + '>' + key + '</div>';
    }
    $(selector + ' .menu').html(html);
    $(selector).dropdown();
}
$("#programmetype").dropdown({
    onChange: function (val) {
        if (val == "val1")
            setDinamicOptions('#servicetype', {Saloon:'val1', Truck:'val2'});
        if (val == "val2")
            setDinamicOptions('#servicetype', {Abraham:'val1', Leopard:'val2'});
        if (val == "val3")
            setDinamicOptions('#servicetype', {Jet:'val1', Bomber:'val2'});
    }
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want hover effect to open dropdown menu then you don't need to use javascript, instead you can add class simple to your parent div

this is a demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/30/

```
<div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Members <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Players</a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Staff</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for setting dropdown content just in time (for example based on some dynamic criteria) is using the remoteApi, that is a particularly unfortunate name for the data binding features of the SemanticUI dropdowns.

Follow instructions here: http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#mocking-responses