# Semantic-UI: Dynamically added item to dropdown can't be selected

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am trying to dynamically add items to dropdown but when items are added, they can't be selected. Here is what I've done so far:

html:

```
<select name="tags" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
<option value="" >Enter some tags</option>
  <option value="css">css</option>
  <option value="html">html</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$dropdown = $('.ui.dropdown');

$dropdown.dropdown({
    maxSelections: 3
});

$dropdown.dropdown('add optionValue', 'ruby');
$dropdown.dropdown('add optionValue', 'python');

$dropdown.dropdown('set selected', ['css', 'html', 'python', 'ruby']);
```

`css` and `html` are selected but `ruby` and `python` aren't while `ruby` and `python` are added to dropdown and you can select them manually. You can find the jsfiddle at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/efp8z6Ln/299/).

Also I've seen following question: [Semantic-UI Dynamic Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164660/semantic-ui-dynamic-dropdown) but I don't think it's a good way to add items to dropdowns.

Comment: Ruby and Python aren't to be found in the dropdown in your jsfiddle.